# Problemas con function, no puedo resolver esta consigna

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function

Realizar el algoritmo que permita el ingreso por prompt de las notas (validar entre 0 y 10 usar una funcion), el nombres de 10 alumnos, informar por alert:

### El promedio de las notas totales.
La nota más baja y el nombre de la persona.

Buenas, intento hacer este código pero no sé como verificar entre 0 y 10 con una function y sacar el promedio, he intentado de todo. Si alguien puede ayudarme le agradezco mucho!

```
<script>
//array de alumnos y notas
var Alumnos = [10];
var Notas = [Alumnos];
Alumnos[0]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del primer alumno: ");
Alumnos[1]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del segundo alumno: ");
Alumnos[2]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del tercer alumno: ");
Alumnos[3]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del cuarto alumno: ");
Alumnos[4]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del quinto alumno: ");
Alumnos[5]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del sexto alumno: ");
Alumnos[6]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del septimo alumno: ");
Alumnos[7]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del octavo alumno: ");
Alumnos[8]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del noveno alumno: ");
Alumnos[9]=prompt("Ingresar nombre del decimo alumno: ");
function validar(Notas) {
    if (Notas<0 && Notas>10) {
        alert("Se ingresaron notas incorrectas");
    }
}
for (var i = 0 ; i < Alumnos.length; i++) {
    Notas[i]=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el precio del producto "+Alumnos[i]));
    alert("Alumno: "+Alumnos[i]+" Nota: "+Notas[i]);
    //Mostrar alumnos y notas
}
//buscamos el número más pequeño
var menorNota= Notas[0];
for (var i = 0; i < Notas.length ; i++) {
    if (Notas[i] < menorNota) {
    menorNota = Notas[i];
    }
}
alert("La nota más baja es: "+menorNota);
```

Comment: Tu función validar asume que Notas es un número, no un array de ellos. Podrías hacer algo como `return Notas.every(nota => nota > 0 && nota <=10);`

Answer (score 0):

Yo comprobaría la nota en el momento de introducirla por el teclado, asegurarme que esté entre 0 y 10 y además que es un valor numérico.
Puedes usar un bucle do que se ejecuta mientras que se cumpla una condición (valor introducido fuera de los límites o no numérico).
Además en el momento de aceptar la nota pues las vas sumando para tener el total que luego usas para calcular la media.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < Alumnos.length; i++) {
    do{
      Notas[i] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese el precio del producto " + Alumnos[i]));
    }while ((Notas[i]< 0 && Notas[i] >10) || isNaN(Notas[i]));
    total += Notas[i];
    alert("Alumno: "+Alumnos[i]+" Nota: "+Notas[i]);
    //Mostrar alumnos y notas
}
//buscamos el número más pequeño
var menorNota= Notas[0];
for (var i = 0; i < Notas.length ; i++) {
    if (Notas[i] < menorNota) {
      menorNota = Notas[i];
    }
}
  
alert("La nota más baja es: "+menorNota);
alert("la media es "+(total/Alumnos.length));
```

La media también puedes calcularla mediante reduce:

```
media = Notas.reduce((t,v)=>t+v)/Notas.length
```